# Django model relationships compared to laravel ORM

Tags: python, django-models, orm

For example when i try to loop through all the objects in the Post model in the homepage together with their comments and the number of likes of each of them in a list, it doesn’t work like it does in laravel. Like this;

Homepage.html

post 1 (0 likes)
comment 1
comment 2
post 2 (5 likes)
comment 1
post 3 (1 like)
post 4 (3 likes)
comment 1
comment 2
comment 3

There is a separate comments table and  a likes table that were connected to the post model through the OneToMany relationship using Post model as the foreignkey.

```
{% for post in posts %
     <p>{{post.title}}</p>
     {% len(post.likes) %}
     {% for comment in post.comments %}
        <p> {{comment.body}} </p>
     {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

In laravel blade this code works fine with blade template and loop through the posts, their comments and likes.

How do i fix the django code to do thesame because the documentation on model relationships hasn’t been so helpful in explaining this.

Comment: `post.comments.all` will work, and since you cannot call functions/methods, you need to use a filter: `post.likes|length` or simply (if likes is a relation) `post.likes.count`

Comment: Share your view, you are here creating an N+1 problem.